# Append to file with single function

Tags: php, file

I know that to append to a file, I need to do this:

```
fopen('file.txt', a);
fwrite('file.txt', 'stuff');
fclose('file.txt');
```

But can I do it with a single function, like `file_append_contents('file.txt', 'stuff')`?

EDIT: I know about `file_put_contents()`, but iirc that overwrites the whole file.

Comment: [**`file_put_contents()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net//manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) with the `FILE_APPEND` option.

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/filename', $data, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
file_put_contents()
```

That's what you're looking for :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: But that overwrites the whole file... doesn't it?

Comment: @Bluefire It has an option to append the file, just read the documentation

Comment: @Darhazer Ah, didn't notice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use

```
file_put_contents('file1.txt',file_get_contents('file2.txt'));
```