# PHP fwrite insert blank line at the end

Tags: php

I have this code :

```
$fp = fopen($pathAndFileName, "a+");
$n4 = count($output2);
for ($iii=0; $iii<$n4; $iii++)
{
 fwrite($fp, $output2[$iii]);

}

 fclose($fp);
```

For example the result is :

```
A
B
(blank line)
```

How can remove the final blank line?

Thanks

Comment: why would you want to do that? The next time you write to the file, your data's going to look like `A (line break) B (line break) CAB` no line breaks.

Comment: Can't you just `file_put_contents(rtrim(file_get_contents()))`?  I don't know what `$output2` is.  Do you want to do `file_put_contents($pathAndFileName, implode(PHP_EOL, $output2))`?

Comment: Or even `FILE_APPEND` https://stackoverflow.com/q/24722598/2943403

Answer (score -1):

You can use the funcion [rtrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) on the last line of the file, to trim any trailing whitespace (including newlines) on that line.

```
$fp = fopen($pathAndFileName, "a+");
$n4 = count($output2);
for ($iii=0; $iii<$n4; $iii++) {
    $output = $output2[$iii]);
    if($iii == $n4-1) {
        $output = rtrim($output);
    }
    fwrite($fp, $output);
}
fclose($fp);
```